# springboot delete a row and after that show / reload same page (without that row)

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, spring-boot, hibernate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8fKq.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Xtl.png)I want delete data from table and after delete a row that table page should be reloaded (without that row e.g. deleted)
single row is deleted perfectly but instead of reload i am seening "request:/form" text on browser.

Help me as i am new to springboot. Thanks

```
   -------------------------------
    ****homecontroller.java****
    ---------------------------
        
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form")
@CrossOrigin
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private StarFormRepository starFormRepositoy;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public StarForm saveForm(@RequestBody StarForm starForm) {
        return this.starFormRepositoy.save(starForm);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<StarForm> StarFormGet()
    {
        return this.starFormRepositoy.findAll();
        
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/form/delete/{id}")
        public String delete(@PathVariable long id) {
            starFormRepositoy.deleteById(id);
            return "redirect:/form/";
        }

}

--------------------------------------------
****index.html****
--------------------------------------------


      <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ url: "/form/get",
        success: function(data){
               var $tbody = $('#t1');
                $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
                console.log(val)
                var $div = $("<tr>");
                var url = "/form/delete/" + val.id;
                $div.append("<td>" + val.id + "</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.name +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.fName +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.mName +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.lName +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.age +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.associatedRotaryClub +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.associatedRotaryClubOther +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.rotaryAlumni +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.rotaryAlumniOther +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.firstContact +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.secondContact +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.email +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.bizAddress +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.eduQualification +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.website +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.bizCategory +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.resAddress +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.preferredComm +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.joiningInterest +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td>"+ val.joiningInterestOther +"</td>")
                $div.append("<td><a href="+url+">delete</a></td>")
                $tbody.append($div);                    
            });
        }});
});
 </script>  

<script>
  submit = function() {
    console.log($('#name'));
    var data = {
      name : $('#name').val(),
      fName : $('#fName').val(),
      mName : $('#mName').val(),
      lName : $('#lName').val(),
      age : $('#age').val(),
      associatedRotaryClub : $('input[name=associatedRotaryClub]:checked').val(),
      associatedRotaryClubOther : $('#associatedRotaryClubOther').val(),
      rotaryAlumni : $('input[name=rotaryAlumni]:checked').val(),
      rotaryAlumniOther : $('input[name=rotaryAlumniOther]:checked').val(),
      firstContact : $('#firstContact').val(),
      secondContact : $('#secondContact').val(),
      email : $('#email').val(),
      bizAddress : $('#bizAddress').val(),
      eduQualification : $('#eduQualification').val(),
      website : $('#website').val(),
      bizCategory : $('#bizCategory').val(),
      resAddress : $('#resAddress').val(),
      preferredComm : $('input[name=preferredComm]:checked').val(),
      joiningInterest : $('input[name=joiningInterest]:checked').val(),
      joiningInterestOther : $('#joiningInterestOther').val()
    }
    console.log(data);
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/form',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Add the code that calls the submit function.

Comment: And please post the actual code and pictures of it.

Comment: What Request Type is the delete method (GET, POST, DELETE) ? Please share the code of your WebApplicationController,  where you configure your HTML pages for a request.

Comment: Added code for delete, get all data, and controller file code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think the problem is, you are trying to redirect it to `"redirect:/form/"`, but in your controller I don't see a request mapping to a default `/` Get Request.

The other problem is your html is index.html, and simply redirecting to `/form/` won't work.

I would suggest you to make the following changes and try.

Try 1:
In your HomeController.java, instead of `return "redirect:/form/"` try `return "index"`. This should render your index.html again when you hit delete.

Try 2:
If that doesn't work, you might have to add a RequestMapping for a default `/` GET request as follows.

In your HomeController.java add the following code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectHome() {
    return "index";
}
```

This should resolve your problem.

Having said all of this, the way you are trying to handle Delete action is not a good practice.

- According to REST principles, delete request must be of the RequestType DELETE.
- Your Delete controller method should just delete the row, and return a success.
- Your delete button on the UI must be a trigger a javascript Ajax function that calls the delete API and on success remove the row from the table, and not redirect using an Anchor Tag `<a>`

Reference on how to handle Form Submit in Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: Thanks sir @kousick shanmugam nagaraj